# Designing a polymorphic class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

We have a rails app that uses 2 models: Image and Video.
They are both belongs_to a collection entity.
What happens is that if we want to query or use both types in a unified way - we cant. So if we want to fetch the last 15, we query twice and then sort and then take the 15 again.
If we want to find() some id, we need always to get what type it is - video or image...

So we were thinking about how to solve this.
Is holding an Asset model that points to either one?
Will it be able to be eagerly loaded?

In my vision it has to be Asset.find(_id) and I will get either Image or Video agnostically.

What is the easiest or most correct way to solve this in Rails?

Thanks!

Comment: I think `enum` in rails is what you are looking for. http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html. Hope this help.

Comment: There is no correct way to solve this as its an example of [Object-relational impedance mismatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch). Common ways to solve this is by using single table or multiple table inheritance.

Comment: Using STI as described by Tamer will allow you to do MediaItem.find(id) and get a video or image model depending on the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Single Table Inheritance](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#single-table-inheritance) to achieve this goal.

Let's say you have a model called `Media`:

```
rails g model media_item type:string <other attributes here>
```

Then you inherit from it two models: `Video` and `Image`, like this:

```
rails g model video --parent=MediaItem
rails g model image --parent=MediaItem
```

Now in in your models:

```
class MediaItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :collection
end

class Collection < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :media_items
end
```

This approach comes with some disadvantages though. For example, subclasses may have many different attributes, and you could end up having too many attributes that are used in one subclass but not the other, and vice versa.

There are some workarounds for that, like having a `properties` field that is hash-like and contains subclass-specific attributes. But this may also become problematic if you need to index on a specific property and your DB doesn't support such indexes. Or you could just make a separate attributes 
table for each subclass with 1-to-1 relationship, a way known as multiple table inheritance, but this also has its drawbacks. It all depends on your specific use case.

Comment: "Or you could just make a separate attributes table for each subclass with 1-to-1 relationship." - Thats what is commonly called multiple table inheritance.

Comment: @max Thanks very much, I actually didn't know it has a name lol. Will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: I am looking to use the models i have now. What you are suggesting is I should convert my whole models and app to be MediaItem.